# Axiomatic Semantics - How to calculate a weakest precondition

Tags: semantics, preconditions, formal-methods

Here is example:

```
x = y + 1;
y = y - 2;
{y < 3}
```

What is weakest precondition of this example?

I think maybe y < 3 is an answer.

If not, can you tell me why, in detail?

Comment: Why do you think it might be? What do you think your references tell you to do to find a wp here? Please read [ask] and google 'stackexchange homework'.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my first mistaken attempt at an answer based on a quick read of [Predicate transformer semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_transformer_semantics#Sequence)

```
  WP( x := y + 1; y := y - 2, y < 3 )        # Initial problem
= WP( x := y + 1, WP( y := y - 2, y < 3 ) )  # Sequence rule
= WP( x := y + 1, y < 5 )                    # Assignment rule
= WP( x - 1 = y, y < 5 )                     # solve for y  <--- this is wrong!
= WP( x - 1 < 5 )                            # Assignment rule
= x < 6                                      # solve for x
```

However as pointed out by [Kris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/496426/kris) since `x := y + 1` is an assignment to `x` which doesn't affect `y` the weakest precondition for `y` should just be `y < 5` so the correct answer should be

```
  WP( x := y + 1; y := y - 2, y < 3 )         # Initial problem
= WP( x := y + 1, WP( y := y - 2, y < 3 ) )   # Sequence rule
= WP( x := y + 1, y < 5 )                     # Assignment rule
= y < 5
```

Thanks also to [philipxy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3404097/philipxy) for identifying errors in my syntax especially `:=` vs `=` since that made it easier to mistake assignments for equations which was part of my initial confusion.

Comment: Surely the weakest pre-condition must mention y? Intuitively, the weakest precondition is `y < 5`. Your 'solve for y' step is invalid, the '=' sign is an assignment, not an arithmetical equality. There is no mention of 'x', hence `wp(x = y + 1; y < 5) = y < 5`, and we're done.

Comment: You still have a typo or misunderstand. The code means `x := y + 1; y := y - 2;`. The post condition is *y < 3*. Your reference uses WP( code, condition ). So the last semi-colons of your WPs should be commas. PS Please just keep your question or answer up to date in the best self-contained form. Old versoions are accessible via the 'edited' link. Also this question "does not show any research effort", downvote.

Comment: Thanks.  The syntax was definitely a problem and I agree it would be better if the OP showed more of their work.  I left the old version mainly for the benefit of the OP and anyone else like myself discovering this topic for the first time so that they would see and avoid the error.